# html5 geolocation to php variable

Tags: php, html, location

How can I get current location from android phone with use HTML5 and assaign it to php variable like $lat and $lon ? I have code like that but how can I use it ?

```
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
  {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  doSomething();

  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is strictly client-side. You'll need to use a postback of some sort - AJAX being the weapon of choice for this. From there, store it in whatever session you're using for the user and voila, job done.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to send the coordinates to a PHP handler function so you can store them anywhere you want (DB, session etc.) and make the handler send the values to your function.

I'm suggesting a handler function as that is my style of doing things, but you can send the data to your function directly.

Also, you can opt for a time triggered event, like let's say send the data every 5 seconds or user event, the sky's the limit from there.

Comment: yes , that's what I want to learn but how ? do you know about this topic tutorial on internet?